# Elsevier API advanced search query features

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

My program prompts the user for a topic, and their input query is passed through the URL:

`https://api.elsevier.com/content/search/sciencedirect?query={query}`

The relevant full-text documents of articles pertaining to the query are then returned. However, depending on the input query, a very large number of articles could be returned if a broad query is submitted. Vice versa, a narrow query might not return enough results.

I am looking for a way to narrow down my search query to solve this issue. I have already read the documentation for features such as metadata and boolean operators, but I'd like to find something more effective.

Comment: Why are metadata and boolean operators not effective?